# How to concatenate variables with selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I'm having problems with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/vitordhers/fm8a14x6/2/

I intend to make subcategories appear if at least one check-box is checked, however when I uncheck the check-boxes, the subcategories don't disappear, since they share the same class with those from the other category.

In order to apply the code to one paragraph only, I tried to concatenate the $this selector with :checked selector, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
    var $line = $('.l' + $(this).data('value'));
    var n = $( $this+"input:checked" ).length;

    alert(n);

    if(n == 0){
        $($line).hide(); //if there are none checked, hide visible elements
    } else {
        $($line).show(); //otherwise (some are selected) fadeIn - if the div is hidden.
    }
});
```

Could anybody help me in this case? Thanks in advance

Comment: `$this` is not defined.

Comment: If you're trying to find a child item, then `$("input:checked", this)`

Comment: Side note, don't do `$($line)`.  It's already a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checked", this)
```

did the trick.